# Dynamic data reloading with Ajax and pagination

Tags: javascript, html, json, ajax, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to get information about animals and their speeds from an API.

[image]

The information should be saved in a table with 5 columns. it should look something like this:

[image]

you will find the code that I have written so far underneath. The problem is that only the two buttons load, but not the table with the information. Do you have an idea what the error could be?

```
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Test</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
        integrity="sha384-1srTifKwwmIWHsyIaapyeJQY2XxzfjIHpftPvwHSi97Mfm4cZNKDBAdVSrtRvti5" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script> src = "https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.7.1.min.js"
        integrity = "sha384-1H217gwSVyLSIfaLxHbE7dRb3v4mYCKbpQvzx0cegeju1MVsGrX5xXxAvs/HgeFs"
        crossorigin = "anonymous"
    </script>
</head>

<body class="text-center">
    <br />
    <button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" id="prev">Prev</button>
    <button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" id="next">Next</button>
    <br />
    <table id="table" class="table table-striped table-striped table-hover">
        <tbody id="tableBody" />
    </table>
    <script src=" myScript.js">
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

//Below the myScript.js

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    /*Variablen  */
    var counter = -5;
    var end = false;

    $("#next").click(function () {
        if (!final) {
            counter = counter + 5;
        }
        $.get("http://localhost:8080/webService/api/velocitiespagination?start=" + counter, function (velocities) {
            createTable(velocities);
        });
    });
    $("#prev").click(function () {
        counter = counter - 5;
        if (counter < 5){
            counter = 0;
        }
        $.get("http://localhost:8080/webService/api/velocitiespagination?start=" + counter, function (velocities) {
            createTable(velocities);
        });
    });


    createTable(velocities);
});

function createTable(velocities) {
    var text = "<tbody><tr><th>Tier<>/th><th>Maximalgeschwindigkeit Tier</th></tr>";
    $.each(velocities, function (key, velocity) {
        text = text + "<tr><td>" + velocity.animal + "</td><td>" + velocity.velocity + "</td></tr>";
    });
    text += "</tbody>"
    $("#myTable").html(text);

    end = velocities.length === 0;
}
```

Comment: Are you getting any errors showing in the console?

Comment: Maybe it's this part: $("#myTable").html(text);
The table in your example has the id "table" and not "myTable"

Comment: @Karakuchi no, i did´t get any errors in the console

Comment: Because the api you are calling is not publicly accessible it is very hard to actually test your code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I imagine if you look at the console you'll see errors about `$(...).ready()` not being a function because you're not loading jQuery.

You are declaring variables `src`, `integrity` and `crossorigin` when you do this

```
<script> src = "https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.7.1.min.js"
        integrity = "sha384-1H217gwSVyLSIfaLxHbE7dRb3v4mYCKbpQvzx0cegeju1MVsGrX5xXxAvs/HgeFs"
        crossorigin = "anonymous"
    </script>
```

You want them as attributes on the script tag, like this

```
<script src = "https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.7.1.min.js"
        integrity = "sha384-1H217gwSVyLSIfaLxHbE7dRb3v4mYCKbpQvzx0cegeju1MVsGrX5xXxAvs/HgeFs"
        crossorigin = "anonymous" >
    </script>
```